# Sequelize transaction issue

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I use transaction in sequelize as following code:

```
return await db.sequelize.transaction(async t => {
        const insertedClient = await db.Client.create(newClient);
        await insertedClient.addConseiller(conseiller_id); 
        console.log(insertedClient);
        return insertedClient.dataValues.client_id;
    });
```

No issue it works if something goes wrong rollback done.

But on this case

```
return await db.sequelize.transaction(async t => {
        const insertedPool = await db.Pool.create(newPool);
        pool.pool_variable.forEach(async (variable) => {
            await insertedPool.addVariable(variable.variable_id);               
        });
        return insertedPool.dataValues.pool_id;
    });
```

It doesn't work.
Commit is done just after db.Pool.create
And no rollback after an error

```
[1] Executing (7320ac52-b957-428d-b94e-07f0ce95af73): START TRANSACTION;
[1] Executing (default): INSERT INTO `pool` (`pool_id`,`pool_nom`,`pool_type_culture`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?);
[1] Executing (7320ac52-b957-428d-b94e-07f0ce95af73): **COMMIT;**
[1] Executing (default): SELECT `pool_variable_ref_pool`, `pool_variable_ref_variable` FROM `pool_variable` AS `pool_variable` WHERE `pool_variable`.`pool_variable_ref_pool` = 62 AND `pool_variable`.`pool_variable_ref_variable` IN (11);
[1] Executing (default): SELECT `pool_variable_ref_pool`, `pool_variable_ref_variable` FROM `pool_variable` AS `pool_variable` WHERE `pool_variable`.`pool_variable_ref_pool` = 62 AND `pool_variable`.`pool_variable_ref_variable` IN (21);
[1] Executing (default): SELECT `pool_variable_ref_pool`, `pool_variable_ref_variable` FROM `pool_variable` AS `pool_variable` WHERE `pool_variable`.`pool_variable_ref_pool` = 62 AND `pool_variable`.`pool_variable_ref_variable` IN (3100);
[1] Executing (default): INSERT INTO `pool_variable` (`pool_variable_ref_pool`,`pool_variable_ref_variable`) VALUES (62,21);
[1] Executing (default): INSERT INTO `pool_variable` (`pool_variable_ref_pool`,`pool_variable_ref_variable`) VALUES (62,11);
[1] Executing (default): INSERT INTO `pool_variable` (`pool_variable_ref_pool`,`pool_variable_ref_variable`) VALUES (62,3100);
[1] (node:10672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

If someone can explain whats wrong.

Best regards

Comment: You can try replacing `forEach` with `for loop`.

Answer (score 1):

I got it thanks, finally 2 solutions
use foreach(value in array) and not array.foreach((value)=>{});
or
use addVariable**s**(array) to bulk insert

```
return await db.sequelize.transaction(async t => {
    const insertedPool = await db.Pool.create(newPool, { transaction: t });
    //Solution 1
    forEach(variable in pool.pool_variable)
    {
        await insertedPool.addVariable(variable.variable_id, { transaction: t });
    }
    //Solution 2
    const pool_variable = pool.pool_variable.map((variable) => {return variable.variable_id});
    await insertedPool.addVariables(pool_variable, { transaction: t });

    return insertedPool.dataValues.pool_id;
});
```